# How do I make a horizontally scrollable nav bar?

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-lists

I'm trying to make the ul in the nav bar horizontally scroll-able when the screen width get shrinked.

I have looked at answers to some of the similar questions and implemented solutions that seemed to work in my case.

However, the ul and its contents somehow break out of the nav and stay on the next line under the nav. Also,

I thought that setting `position: fixed; overflow-y: hidden;` to the ul would solve the problem. But, instead, the left side of it covers the button placed at the left corner of the nav.

Can anyone help me out??

```
<!--HTML-->
<body>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <div class="btn"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

```
/*CSS*/
.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3rem;
    
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.main-nav .btn {
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;

    background-color: chartreuse;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.main-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 2rem;

}
.main-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 3rem;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 1rem;

    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
.main-nav {
        height: 4rem;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
.main-nav ul {
        position: fixed;
        white-space: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .main-nav ul li {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You need to include your HTML. Otherwise we'd be guessing what the DOM structure is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've tried your code on CodePen, and seems that the only thing that keeps your code from working is the `position: fixed` rule on the `ul` element inside the media query.

In my opinion since you intend to keep all of your items inside the header on the X-Axis, the `overflow-y: hidden` is not needed at all.

I have no idea what exactly you are planning to achieve, but using a scrollable navbar on the X-Axis doesn't seem to be a good practice. Maybe in your application it makes sense, but you might reconsider this. From a UX point of view, it is not the best approach.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for sharing your insight!

Comment: As a beginner, I thought that keeping the items inside the nav is a good way to make it easier to navigate when the screen is smaller. I would like to know how you make this navigation bar user-friendly if you don't mind!

Comment: Well, here it depends a lot on what are your tastes when it comes to Web Design. My advice would be to look at websites you like and see how they behave on mobile screen sizes. Also check current trends in Web Design on YT, there are a lot of great designers sharing their knowledge. You can also try some courses on Udemy to expand your knowledge.